# Volley send request while queue is running

Tags: java, android, android-studio, queue, android-volley

I am making an Android App that is making quite a few network requests at startup. I am using Volley and am adding all the requests to a queue like described here:
https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html

Would it be possible to stop the queue, send a new request (that is executed immediately), then continue with the queue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a second queue and use that when you need it.